# How to get component properties from main component in Angular2?

Tags: angular

been scratching my head like crazy over this.

Basically all I want is in my index.html something like:

```
<app hero="iron man"></app>
```

in my main index.html file, then be able to read the value of hero in my component class.

Been at this for a week, to no avail.  Here's my non-functioning plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FNoNSG0JmBWScSbi4KbT?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your time and response!   Unfortunately, in your scenario you're still not retrieving properties of the  object, you're just putting a second object inside the first and retrieving those properties.

Good news though for anyone else trying to figure it out, it's confirmed as a bug!

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858#event-305799002

Answer (score 0):

I've had to change your example slightly, as at my last check (using Angular 2.0.0-alpha.21), I was having issues retrieving properties from the same component class that was passed to the `bootstrap` method.

However, using a slighty modified example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero',
  properties: {'name':'name'}
})
@View({
  template:`<h1>Hero = {{_name}}</h1>`
})
class Hero {
  _name: string;

  constructor() { 
  };

  set name(name){
    this._name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
})
@View({
  template:
  `
    <div>
      <hero name="iron man"></hero>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Hero]
})
class Application {
  constructor() { };
}

bootstrap(Application);
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<app>
   <hero name="iron man" />
</app>
```

Note that from within your constructor, `_name` will be undefined. To have the property available in your construstor, you can inject it:

```
class Hero {
   _name: string;

   constructor(@Attribute('name') name:string) { 
       this._name = name;
   };
}
```

This is mostly taken from my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991078/binding-to-a-component-property-in-angular2/30000775#30000775)